# Change language for NSDate weekday and month

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I want to display a date like this : weekday 7 month.
I did this and I have the correct syntax.

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

The result logged is : Saturday 16 March. I just want to have the french date, not the english one. I try to set the local time zone but it changes nothing. Do you have an idea of how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the locale of the date formatter using the appropriate `NSLocale` object.

Also, be wary of hard-coded date formats like that.  Your users may not like seeing dates in that format, so you should run the format string through `+[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:]` first.  The WWDC 2012 session "Internationalization Tips & Tricks" had a bunch of useful information about this.

Answer (score 7):

initialize a locale using an identifer.
you can get all available identifiers from

```
[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
```

i believe @"fr_BI" is one of the french identifiers

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_BI"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: To choose the appropriate french identifier, use the code below :    NSArray * bb = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
    NSPredicate * bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'fr'"];
    NSArray * beginWithFr = [bb filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
    for (NSString * elt in beginWithFr) {
        NSLog(@"%@ : %@",elt, [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:elt] localizedStringForLocaleIdentifier:elt]);
    }